# missing labels in matplotlib - bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I draw horizontal bar chart, I see one legend missing in both x axis and y axis when I set yaxis manually like below.

```
bar_locations = np.arange(6)
ax.barh(bar_locations, data ,alpha=.5)
bar_locations = np.arange(6)
# data = [55, 22, 40, 56, 109, 180]
# labels = ['others', u'Belts', u'Apparel & Accessories > Jewelry', u'Jewelry', u'Fragrances', u'Watches']
ax.barh(bar_locations, data ,alpha=.5)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the tick locations as well

```
ax.set_yticks(bar_locations)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

Comment: There is no label for **x**label in the code?! You can set it with `ax.set_xlabel("label")`

Comment: xaxis has drawn based on data automatically right? #data = [55, 22, 40, 56, 109, 180]

Comment: yes correct. For a bar plot it will start at 0 and go to ~10% more than the largest value shown on the axis.

Comment: But final legend in x axis is 150. largest value is 180. It should be more than 190 right?

Comment: As said that is determined automatically. Here, because the next step of 50 would be 200, but the axis is less than 200 long, 200 is not shown as label. You may of course set the labels to your liking, `ax.set_xticks([50,99,137,190])`